# Botskills Connect error: One of the arguments 'cs' or 'ts' should be provided

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I am running the following command to add my own skill to a virtual assistant template bot that I deployed to Azure.

```
botskills connect --botName <YOUR_VA_NAME> --remoteManifest "http://<YOUR_SKILL_MANIFEST>.azurewebsites.net/api/skill/manifest" --luisFolder <YOUR_LUIS_FOLDER_PATH> --cs
```

And even though I provided --cs it just says
'One of the arguments 'cs' or 'ts' should be provided.'
and nothing more. 
However, it works perfectly when I run it to add one of the sample skills to the virtual assistant. I checked the [docs](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/tools/botskills/src/botskills-connect.ts) and tried using the outputFile option, which produced nothing.

What does this error mean? How can I get more information? There are no posts about this error anywhere and no information in the docs either.

Comment: I'm not quite sure. My *assumption* is that it is another one of the parameter values that is throwing it off. I know there was some issue previously related to the --luisFolder value. Something regarding the trailing slash (ie Deployment\Resources\LU\en\ vs  Deployment\Resources\LU\en). Is your value looking similar between your own skill and the sample skill?

Comment: That fixed it for me, thanks.